# ¿Cómo elimino una línea de texto de un archivo sin reescribir todo el archivo?

Tags: java

Hasta ahora tengo este código que busca la línea mediante dos campos de búsqueda y ya de ahí no sé como eliminarla:

```
public void eliminarRegistro(File archivo,String date,String clave) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ControlRevista cr = new ControlRevista();
        boolean encontro = false;
        String lineaTexto = "";
        if (archivo.exists()) {
            BufferedReader readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
            while ((lineaTexto = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] campos = lineaTexto.split(";");
                String[] palabrasClave = campos[4].split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {
                    if (campos[i].equals(date)) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < palabrasClave.length; j++) {
                            if (palabrasClave[j].equals(clave)) {
                                encontro = true;
                                for (int k = 0; k < campos.length; k++) {
                                    System.out.print(campos[k] + ";");
                                }

                                System.out.println("eliminada");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Ayuda por favor, si es posible ¿cómo se elimina la línea del archivo sin tener que crear otro archivo o reescribir todo el contenido menos la línea en cuestión?

Answer (score 6):

Los únicos escenarios en los que no tienes que reescribir nada de un fichero al modificarlo son:

- Estás añadiendo o borrando datos del final del fichero. Basta con poner el puntero al final y hacer las modificaciones oportunas.
- Estás modificando datos en cualquier punto del fichero, pero lo que vas a insertar tiene exactamente el mismo tamaño en bytes que lo que vas a reemplazar. En ese caso puedes poner el puntero/cursor en la posición elegida y escribir los nuevos datos, sobreescribiendo los antiguos.

Fuera de estos dos escenarios, puedes pensar en ficheros como si fueran hojas de papel escritas a lápiz: para meter un nuevo renglón siempre tendrás que borrar lo que venga detrás de la inserción y "desplazarlo". Lo mismo pasa si quieres borrar un renglón y no dejar el espacio vacío: deberás mover los datos que están después un renglón hacia arriba, reescribiendo todo.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente no es la respuesta que buscas, pero para ampliar el espectro de soluciones:

Si se trata de un archivo que se usa para procesar información en lugar de un archivo para ser leído por personas, podés fijar una convención para definir una eliminación lógica de una línea.

Por ejemplo podrias elegir un character poco usado como "~" y sobre-escribir la primera letra de las líneas eliminadas con este caracter. Luego, tu algoritmo de procesamiento debería ignorar las líneas que comienzan con este símbolo.

Ejemplo:

Línea 1 de texto.
~ínea 2 de texto eliminada.
Línea 3 de texto.

El archivo contiene las 3 línas pero desde el punto de vista de un algoritmo que procesa archivos ignorando aquellas líneas que comienzan con "~", el archivo tiene solo dos líneas.